# Set permission/share subfolder to group in a library with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using SP 2013.

I have to set specific permissions to subfolders in a document library

I have the following script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 

Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
   # Use recursion to loop through all subfolders.
   foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
   {

       GetFiles($subFolder)
   }

   if($folder.Name -eq "C" -Or $folder.Name -eq "B3-B6" -Or $folder.Name -eq "C8" -Or $folder.Name -eq "D" -Or $folder.Name -eq "A5" -Or $folder.Name -eq "A1-A4")
        {
            Write-Host "+"$folder.Name

            if($folder.Name -eq "C8")
            {
                $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($web.SiteGroups["HumanResources-HR - C8"])
            }
            else
            { 
                $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($web.SiteGroups["HumanResources-HR - Other"])
            }
            #Get Permission Level, such as "Read", "Contribute", etc

            $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"])
            $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Read"])
            #Grant Access to specified Group
            $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
            #To Remove Access: Call  $item.RoleAssignments.Remove($group) . No Need for objects: roleAssignment, roleDefinition
            $folder.Update();
            Write-Host "Successfully added $($PermissionLevel) to $GroupName group in $($folder.Name)" -foregroundcolor Green
        }
 }

    $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "xxx.xxx.xxx/sites/xxx"


$rfolder=$web.Lists["DOKUMENTNA KNJIŽNICA"].RootFolder
GetFiles($rfolder)
```

and I got an error in the line: $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:29 char:13 + $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

and this happens with all folders.

I tried the same code to set permissions to the whole library and it worked. But it does not work with folders.

Plese help me. Thank you

Comment: Hello. for a folders you can use: Set-Acl : [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder/)

Comment: The error tells that it is not having any value. Could you please check what is coming in `$roleAssignment` and `$folder.RoleAssignments`

Answer (score 0):

You need to break inheritance on the subfolders before you assign new permissions.

`$folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")`

See the script below that does a similar thing.  From [this link](http://sharepoint2010tutor.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/grant-folder-permissionsharepoint-using.html)

I have corrected the formatting and have pasted the entire thing here for better reading:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://myserver/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
function GrantGroupPermission($groupName)
{
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection]$spgroups = $web.SiteGroups
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]$spgroup = $groups[$groupName]
     $sproleass=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipal]$spgroup)
     $folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")
     $sproleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"])
     $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($sproleass);
     Write-Host "Permission provided for group ", $groupName
}

function GrantUserpermission($userName)
{
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$spusers=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$web.SiteUsers
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser=$spusers[$userName]
     $sproleass=new-object  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipal]$spuser)
     $folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")
   $sproleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"])
    $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($sproleass);
    Write-Host "Permission provided for user ", $userName
}

$doclib=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

$foldercoll=$doclib.Folders;
foreach($folder in $foldercoll)
{
 Write-Host $folder.Name
 if($folder.Name.Equals("f2"))
 {
  GrantUserPermission("raj")
 }

}
Write-Host "Completed...."
$web.Close()
$site.Dispose()
```